# Does pretrained Resnet 18 capture correlation of R, G, B modes?

Tags: conv-neural-network, correlation, resnet

I am new to this field and had a concern to which I cannot find any literature. Does pretrained resnet-18 capture correlation between RGB modes? I have modified the resnet to have a greyscale image as my R mode, point cloud data as my G mode and filler matrices of 1 as my B mode. Will it capture the correlation while extracting features? If not what method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The pre-trained ResNet is typically trained with ImageNet dataset, which consists of many RGB images. Consequently, the layers in the front of the ResNet capture correlations between RGB channels, as these models distinguish between classes based on color, shape, contrast, and other factors.

Given that your input consists of grayscale images, point cloud data, and filler matrices for the R, G, and B channels, respectively, there are correlations between these data types. This suggests that the model can capture some relevant features.

Another approach is "multi-modal learning." You can use 3 separate CNN networks to extract features from each of these 3 data types. Then, you can aggregate these extracted features and feed them into the classification network.

[image]